# Como coletar requisitos?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, projeto-de-software

Como posso coletar **requisitos** e elabora-los para **desenvolver um sistema**?
Existe alguma forma de **analise** que eu possa usar para esta finalidade?

Comment: Acho que não tem nenhuma boa resposta sobre este tema por aqui,  tomara que não julguem muito ampla...+1

Comment: Irei ser mais especifico.

Comment: Em muitos fóruns e pesquisa que eu fiz sobre o assunto ainda me deixa com duvidas, são muitos descrições teóricas mais nenhum exemplo pratico de como coletar requisitos.

Comment: É cara, e a experiência demonstra que só um milagre pra reabrirem... uma pena, porque a pergunta é boa, o assunto é super relevante imho, e não tem uma boa resposta sobre isso por aqui... acho que uma boa resposta certamente salvaria essa pergunta de ser considerada ampla demais, como já vi em outros casos, mas não deu tempo hehe...Deixa prá lá, [vida que segue](http://www.devmedia.com.br/engenharia-de-software-2-tecnicas-para-levantamento-de-requisitos/9151). Mas se por acaso você quiser discutir isso, lembre-se de que pode criar um tópico no [meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/)...

Comment: Tranquilo, vou vê se criou um tópico no meta. É que eu acho este assunto muito importante e gostaria que alguém me mostra-se um caminho, mas minha pergunta pareceu não te se enquadrado as regras do site rsrsrs.

Comment: Não é uma questão adequadamente classificada como **projeto-de-software** (*software design*). Remover esta marca facilitará a localização de questões.